# Multilingual admin interface

Tags: nodes, forms, 8, workflows

I have a multilingual website ( english, dutch and german ). The language detection is setup to look at the URL for both interface and content. This results in an admin interface that goes from dutch to english to german depending on which language of a node you are editing.

- I set the interface user language above URL in priority to set the interface based on preference. This does nothing ( it still forces the language from the URL ).
- Next i tried Account administration pages as a detection method for interface. This has the effect that the language is always set to dutch in my case, fine. But now the moment you try to translate a node it always defaults to dutch as well.

I have been messing about with these settings for the better part of the day. What I am trying to achieve is:

- Client can effectively translate nodes but the admin interface is either in there preferred language or just plain english
- On the frontend of the website I want the detection to work based on URL detection ( this one works fine ).

How do I configure this O.o

Thanks